# Why does Portswigger's solution to the lab "SSRF with whitelist-based input filter" work?

Tags: whitelist, ssrf

The URL with the exercise is: https://portswigger.net/web-security/ssrf/lab-ssrf-with-whitelist-filter

The solution is:
`http://localhost:80%2523@stock.weliketoshop.net/admin/delete?username=carlos`

A little simplified (no port specified):
`http://localhost%2523@stock.weliketoshop.net/admin/delete?username=carlos`

We can concentrate simply on:
`http://localhost%2523@stock.weliketoshop.net`

Why is the credential component (everything before the `@`) processed as if everything after the `@` is part of a URL fragment? Before double encoding the `#` character, the URL looks like this:
`http://localhost#@stock.weliketoshop.net`

Why is the `@` even necessary, even after we double encode the `#`? Why does `http://localhost%2523stock.weliketoshop.net` (not no '@') not work? Does the url fragment statement take priority over the credential statement? Why is the `@` ignored in favor of the `#`?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. This looks like a basic URL standards question.

Answer (score 1):

As per the RFC 3986:-

> The userinfo subcomponent may consist of a user name and, optionally,
> scheme-specific information about how to gain authorization to access
> the resource.  The user information, if present, is followed by a
> commercial at-sign ("@") that delimits it from the host.

[RFC3986 section-3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I played with this recently. The SSRF filter is checking to see if the parameter value is an actual URL with a `stock.weliketoshop.net` hostname. It's not a simple string check. That's why if we use `http://localhost%2523stock.weliketoshop.net` it sees it as `http://localhost#...` and not working.

If you add '@' then the filter sees `http://username@stock.weliketoshop.net` which is the accepted hostname. Now if we use `http://localhost%2523@stock.weliketoshop.net` that passes the filter and the web server directs it to `http://localhost#...`

The mysterious part is why `http://localhost%2523@stock.weliketoshop.net/admin` works. It looks like there's another filter that strips everything from %25 until it sees / and concatenates, which leads to`http://localhost/admin`. The normal web server should ignore /admin at the end as it's after the # segment.

I enumerated all the characters and discovered that %252f and $253f also work which are / and ? respectively. I tried `http://localhost%252fadmin%2523@stock.weliketoshop.net` which still passes the filter and makes more sense but again the result was that everything after %25 was stripped so it goes to `http://localhost` only.

My conclusion is that Portswigger created a custom filter for the sake of the tutorial which doesn't exactly resemble a real-world SSRF filter.